# Value as a % of row total in QlikSense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

In QlikSense i want to show value as % of row total, using:

`count(-value-) / count(Total -value-)`

Using the expression above gives me % of totals not row total.

[image: data example]

For example, in the new type column, `T`, % should be `7935 / 8287 = 95.75%` and not `13.71%`

`count(new_type_id) / count(Total New_Type_ID)` gives me the result in attached picture

Answer (score 0):

Im using the following script to recreate your data:

```
Load * inline [
Type, New_Type_ID, new_type_id 
T   , 8287       , 7935
B   , 11942      , 565
C   , 18233      , 674
X   , 13890      , 165 
P   , 5515       , 0
];
```

And using the following expression:

```
Sum(new_type_id) / Sum(total <Type> New_Type_ID)
```

The result will show `95.75%` for `Type = T`

[image: result table]

The difference is in the scope of the `Total` qualifier. In your case `Total` will be called over all results/values and will yield `57 867`.

`Total` can be "forced"/scoped to be called only over specific field(s) values:

`Total <[field name here]>`

From Qlik's [documentation page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/August2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/BasicAggregationFunctions/sum.htm)

[image: docs]

### Update

(as pivot table and split)

Load script to achieve pivot table structure:

```
Load * inline [
Type, Amount
T   , 8287
B   , 11942
C   , 18233
X   , 13890
P   , 5515 
];

Load * Inline [
New_Type, Type, SplitAmount
T       , T       , 7935
B       , T       , 332
C       , T       , 12
X       , T       , 6
P       , T       , 2
T       , B       , 565
B       , B       , 11022
C       , B       , 302
X       , B       , 45
P       , B       , 8
];
```

[image: pivot table]

Measures:

- `Units` calculation`Sum(SplitAmount)`
- `%` calculation `Sum(SplitAmount) / Sum(Total <Type> SplitAmount)`

Comment: Thanks Stefan for you input! Maybe i was not clear enough: the table is matrix, row represent old type letters, T,B,C,X,P, columns are the new type, with same letters, for example, from old type T (which were 8287), 7935 stayed in the same Type T, 332 went to B, 12 went to C, 6 went to X and 2 went to P - so i need this values displayed as % too, like T is 7935 and the % should be 7935/row total od 8287 = 95.75, B 332, 332/8287 4% etc for others as well as the other rows...

Comment: @Dur ive updated my answer by adding another example with pivot table. Ive used the same expression logic (adding aggregation by field in with the `Total` qualifier). Let me know if im missing something :)